# Analyze the grammar structure of this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> We buy things we don't need with money we don't have to impress people we don't like.

I understand the meaning of this sentence, but its structure confuse me because I am not a native speaker.

I know 'we don't need' describe 'things', so the first 'we' and the second 'we' can merge into one sentence, We needn't buy things with money.

but the remaining part I don't know how to deal with.

Comment: No, your paraphrase does not mean the same thing at all. We buy things we don't need (luxuries) with money we don't have (borrowed money) to impress people  who are not our real friends.

Comment: This is from a song, isn't it? You should say where you found this excerpt. It's also missing a few commas (,) or full stops (.) which would help disambiguate the meaning. Google: The quote comes from the movie "Fight club"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I think the quote doesn't need any further punctuation. Though adding punctuation brings up a second possible parsing: "We buy things we don't need with money. We don't have to impress people we don't like." That conveys something quite different from the original.

Comment: @Mari-LouA  it just a quote and comes from [this link](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/25775-we-buy-things-we-don-t-need-with-money-we-don-t)

Comment: @Lawrence the quote without any punctuation, and I can understand the quote, but how to re-construct  the sentence and to clear in grammer structure.

Comment: We buy [non-essentials] [and we get into debt buying them] [and we do this just to create a good image with people we haven't got – and most likely never will have – a friendship with anyway. So we're behaving crazily.] _Perhaps this [near-] paraphrase helps._

Comment: Gramatically it's a main clause with three relative clauses. Main clause: _We buy things with money (in order) to impress people._ First relative clause referring to things: _we don't need_. Second relative clause referring to money: _we don't have_. Third relative clause referring to people: _we don't like_. With all three relative clauses, the relative pronouns are omitted. The sentence can be seen as grammatically OK but I support Mari-Lou's view that it's missing punctuation (for a better reading). Without a comma between 'have' and 'to' one can understand erroneously 'have to' (=must).

Comment: Sorry, '(in order) to impress people' is of course not a part of the main clause. It's a subordinate clause. So, more precisely: We have here a main clause with two relative clauses and a subordinate clause with one realtive clause.

Comment: @Ben A.  thanks your comments, Now I totally understand the sentence both meaning and grammar structure, maybe you can write an answer not an comment, because your explanation is very helpful.

Comment: @Aoerz: Here you are.

Comment: Why do none of the people who are so forthcoming with their advice on simple English that shouldn’t even be on this list ever bother to correct things like “grammer”? Poster, if you write “grammer” you are on the wrong site. Try English Language Learners. I’ve corrected it for. Hope it hasn’t scarred you for life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gramatically it's a main clause (MC) with a subordinate clause (SC). The main clause has two relative clauses (RC1, RC2) - the subordinate clause only one (RC3). All relative clauses are based on additonal information (AI1, AI2, AI3).

**MC** : We buy things with money...
**SC** : ...(in order) to impress people.
***AI1***: *We don't need the things* (mentioned in **MC**).
***AI2***: *We don't have the money* (mentioned in **MC**).
***AI3***: *We don't like the people* (mentioned in **SC**).

**MC**+***RC1***+***RC2***+**SC**+***RC3***:
We buy things *we don't need* with money *we don't have* (in order) to impress people *we don't like*.

With all three relative clauses, the relative pronouns are omitted.

Comment: Let's not forget that the line is a little busy on purpose, for the desired rat-a-tat quality.

Answer (score 0):

We buy A with B (in order) to impress C, where

- A = things (that) we do not need
- B = money (that) we do not have
- C = people (whom) we do not like.